# Typescript and d3

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I have an app that uses the d3 library. In typescript code, in order to use d3 successfully (i.e., without compiler error TS2686, d3 refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module), I have to include the  line:
`import * as d3 from 'd3';`
Problem with that is that it emits:
`require('d3');`
in the JavaScript. That's not where the d3 library is in our application. It's under the root of the web app, in a directory called 'd3'. Also, I don't need it in the JavaScript at all because our index.html loads it as a global.
Having a hard time figuring out how to get the TypeScript source to allow me to reference d3 without the import.

Comment: It sounds like you are using `d3` as a global, not a module. First of all, why not use it as a module (ex install with `npm`)? If you want to use D3 as a global from within a module I think you need to manually declare it as a global.

Comment: I can declare it as a global, but then TypeScript won't understand when I do things like `d3.selectAll(...)`. I installed the d3 typings. They're under node_modules/@types, put there by npm install. d3's index.d.ts declares d3 as a namespace. It's all resolved in the editor, but it gives me the error on the reference to d3. But all of what d3 declares is known by the TypeScript environment while editing.

Comment: Understanding the types is different from the code actually working. How are you including D3 into your project?

Comment: This is a pretty big project, mostly written in JavaScript, using lots of dojo and d3, and we have one new widget hierarchy that's been under development for a few weeks, being written in TypeScript. The d3 code is packaged into the web app under web app root in the d3 directory. The TypeScript source is being written in the source tree, outside of the WebContent folder, being compiled into the WebContent hierarchy. The TypeScript source is configured via tsconfig.json to understand that the d3 typings are under node_modules/@types/d3. The application runs w/o errors. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Gotcha. So you need to declare `d3` as a global, TS currently just doesn't allow you to use a typedef as a namespace from within a module (it only works from a non-module file). You can declare `d3` as a global with all the typings using this method: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10178#issuecomment-263787616

Comment: Added an answer with an example.

Comment: Wow. Magic. Thanks so much! I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't count because I don't have enough points.

Comment: I believe you can still mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two possible options:

## Suppress the warning

As of [TypeScript 3.5 a `--allowUmdGlobalAccess` flag was added](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#the---allowumdglobalaccess-flag) to allow you to access global definitions from module files. In your case this will mean you can use `d3` as a global namespace without having an `import` or `require` statement. This will obviously apply to all module files in your project and for any other UMD type definitions (like React, for example) so just be aware that it may not be correct in all contexts, depending on your code setup and libraries in use.

## Declare a global namespace

Previously to TS 3.5 and without the `--allowUmdGlobalAccess` flag [UMD typedefs can't be referenced as a global namespace](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10178) from within a module file. (It only allows you to reference a global namespace from a non-module file.) This is an intentional safe-guard against accidentally referring to a global namespace that is not available in a strictly module-based project. The [workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10178#issuecomment-263787616) is to manually declare a global namespace within your project:

```
// global.d.ts
import * as _d3 from "d3";

declare global {
  const d3: typeof _d3;
}
```

Now you can refer to `d3` from modules without importing from `"d3"`, and you should still get all the correct type checking on the `d3` object based on `@types/d3`.

This has the advantage over `--allowUmdGlobalAccess` in that it's very explicit about your particular code setup. In other words it won't inadvertently let you compile other UMD modules that your code setup is not providing globally.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by Aaron Beall is perfect for the very specific situation op is in, but more generally, if you want to use TypeScript with D3 these days, [DefinitelyTyped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3) is the way to go. You can just

```bash
npm i d3
npm i -D @types/d3
```

and

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

like with any other `@types` library.