# D3Js not directly supports TypeScripts, what is the alternate which support typescript especially with Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, data-visualization, angular6

Currently am working on new project for HR Analytics  using Python, R, MySQL and Angular 6 as front end UI. 
For Data Visualization I'm trying to use D3js.
D3Js not directly supports TypeScripts and In Angular 6 we have to use typescript.
And I tried other wrapper and those all are limited graphs.
Since I new to Data Visualization,
Please suggest,
what is the best JS which support typescript and Data Visualization?
atleast for basic charts

Note: I tried NvD3 and Angular-NvD3, those are not updated for more than a year.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try echarts, the angular version of the package in github:https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts

Comment: Thanks HaiyangLong, but it is not expandable like D3Js. I will check and let you know. :)

Comment: @user2644848 Echarts has detailed api, official document address:[ https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/tutorial.html ]

Comment: Thanks HaiyangLong, Yes I found some useful Charts & Graphs in Echarts.

Comment: Haiyang, Can we use or extend the chart or graphs from eCharts library while using this ngx-chart? Because I could many charts in eCharts but limited charts in ngx-chart. I am sure this is the best one if we can extend the chart/graphs from eCharts library

Answer (score 1):

D3.js can be used with TypeScript:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3
- [Typescript and d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305957/typescript-and-d3)

Comment: Thanks Paleo, I will check the link and let you know.